# Agregar Js después de que se cargue la pagina

Tags: javascript, html, html5, fetch

Tengo un archivo **HTML** con **Js** que envía una petición `fetch()` con valores `POST`  a una página .php y devuelve un **HTML** que después hago un `document.body.innerHTML += html;` pero el problema es de que en el html que devuelve hay un `<script>` y ese script no se ejecuta porque la pagina ya se cargo.

¿Que puedo hacer para que se ejecute el **JavaScript**?

Answer (score 0):

La línea:
    document.body.innerHTML += html;

Lo que hace es modificar la propiedad *innerHTML*, pero no ejecuta el código que contiene.

Para cargar un script y que se ejecute, deberías utilizar el DOM para crear y añadir nodos al head (u otra sección de código)

Aquí tienes un ejemplo que funciona:

```
var node_script = document.createElement('script');
node_script.src = "http://mydomain.com/script.js";
node_script.type ='text/javascript';
node_script.defer = true;

var node_head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
node_head.appendChild(script);
```

Fíjate en la propiedad **node_script.src**, tienes que asignarle la url a tu script. Puede ser absoluta (como en el ejemplo) o bien relativa. Lo que no puedes pasarle, es la carpeta en el servidor o tu local.

Comment: No es un script externo, es un script dentro del html, donde recibe valores de PHP